# Group CheckBoxes In Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, selection

Can you group `CheckBoxes` in MS Word 2013? It seems like I should be able to select more than one since under the `Developer` Ribbon heading the `Group` button exists, but I can't seem to select more than one `CheckBox` at a time. I tried selecting more than one `CheckBox` with the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key but I'm unable to select more than one (whereas in previous version of Word, the cursor used to change to a plus icon).

I remember this functionality in previous iterations but I can't figure out how to do it in 2013.  I can't even find the `RadioButton` control which seems suited for this.  It seems like they changed the controls model because I see all the old controls listed under a button called `Legacy Tools` and similarly named ones available.  Can anyone explain why they moved away from Active X/what this means for controls?